# neo4j disable legacy lucene index

Tags: neo4j

I have a project that requires lucene 4.  Neo4j is automatically trying to grab lucene 3.6  I have found some scattered indications online about legacy indexing being dependent upon lucene but schema indexing not dependent, schema indexing being recommended over legacy, etc.  How can I exclude lucene dependency altogether via maven and my source (code, properties, etc.) ?  Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to do that by easy way.

One option is to use [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Second one is to write your own Custom Class Loader for JARs which are in conflict.